# What is an Intermittent Word™?

Tags: word-property

<sub>*This is in the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

If a word conforms to a certain rule, I call it an Intermittent Word™. Use the following examples to find the rule:

| Intermittent Words™ | Not Intermittent Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| Newfoundland | Yukon |
| Currants | Sultanas |
| Dynamo | Engine |
| Bear | Lion |
| North | South |
| Brandy | Whiskey |
| America | Canada |
| Mountain | Peak |

CSV version:

```
Intermittent Words™, Not Intermittent Words™
Newfoundland, Yukon
Currants, Sultanas
Dynamo, Engine
Bear, Lion
North, South
Brandy, Whiskey
America, Canada
Mountain, Peak
```

Comment: Are there more words like this?

Comment: Yes there could be many more words like this...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Every Intermittent Word™...

> begins and ends with a two-letter symbol for an [element](https://iupac.org/what-we-do/periodic-table-of-elements/).

For example:

> Newfoundland: Neon (Ne) and Neodymium (Nd) 
>  Currants: Copper (Cu) and Tennessine (Ts) 
>  Dynamo: Dysprosium (Dy) and Molybdenum (Mo) 
>  Bear: Beryllium (Be) and Argon (Ar) 
>  North: Nobelium (No) and Thorium (Th) 
>  Brandy: Bromine (Br) and Dysprosium (Dy) 
>  America: Americium (Am) and Calcium (Ca) 
>  Mountain: Molybdenum (Mo) and Indium (In)

I assume they are called Intermittent Words™...

> as a clue. Intermittent (occurring at irregular intervals) is the opposite of periodic (occurring regularly), and the answer can be found using the Periodic Table of Elements.

Comment: Wow that's gotta be it, nice work!

Comment: That's it...let gnovice's halo gleam forth!

Answer (score 1):

All Intermittent Words are

> basically, opposite vector to Not Intermittent words

Basically,

> Newfoundland is below Yukon geographically, Currants are darker then Sultanas(below in colors), South is opposite to North, Bear lives North and Lions South, America below Canada, And Peak is on top of the Mountain.

Comment: How is North below South?

Comment: Screwed this one, wrong wording. Going to fix that

Comment: It's common in these kinds of puzzles to provide opposites in both columns, but the rule should only relate to the word itself.

Answer (score -5):

Well, here is an answer:

> Intermittent words are those whose first letter when combined with random numbered (between 1 and 4 - and these numbers are intermittent) letters from left to right form some meaningful words and the same is not the case with Not Intermittent words.

For example:

> NEWFOUNDLAND can form NOUN/NUN (by skipping 3/4 consecutive letters),
>  CURRANTS can form CAN (by skipping 3 letters),
>  DYNAMO can form DAM/DO (by skipping 2 / 4 letters),
>  BEAR can form BAR (by skipping 1 letter) and so on.

Comment: WHISKEY can form WISE, so it is intermittent word following your logic

Comment: What about North vs South? I can't see how this argument is applied consistently for these two.

Comment: @Novarg well, my words illustrated are having only **one** skip. No two skips. Two arrive at WISE from WHISKEY, you need two skips!

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay another example then: CANADA - [CAD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cad)